# when i am trying to send mail from server getting fatal error?

Tags: php, sendmail

this is my mail script trying to send mail from my server.

```
<?php
$subject = 'This is an HTML email.';
$smtp_server = 'smtp.mydomain.com';
$from = $smtp_username = 'info@mydomail.com';
$smtp_password = 'mypassword';
$html = 'This is an <strong>HTML</strong> <i>formatted</i> email!';
$text = strip_tags($html);
$to = 'ramsai.php@gmail.com';
//$cc = array('foo@example.com');
//$bcc  array('bar@example.com', 'baz@example.com');

// send the message
$result = sendMail($subject, $smtp_server, $smtp_username, $smtp_password, $html, $text, $to);

// check to see if the message was sent properly
if ($result !== true) {
    echo 'There was an error sending the message. ('.$result.')';
} // end if the message was not sent properly
else {
    echo 'Message sent successfully.';
} // end else the message was sent properly


?>
```

When i am trying to run this script in my godaddy server i am getting fatal error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sendMail() in /home/content/99/7916299/html/EMRXXX/EMRnew/Patient/sendmail1.php on line 13

Thank you in advance,
Ramsai

Comment: take a look at http://pear.php.net/Mail its very easy to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function sendMail()**

Means you forgot to include your `sendMail()` user function. Because there is no native php `sendMail()` function...

You should use the native [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function and setup your server to use sendmail (smtp) within your *php.ini* file:

`mail($to,$subject,$content,$headers);`

Comment: Lawrence Cherone has the right info.  A couple other points to help fine tune this is the correct server for sending email from Go Daddy shared hosting is "relay-hosting.secureserver.net"  You will need to replace this in the line:

    $smtp_server = 'smtp.mydomain.com';

Also, you do not need a username nor a password to connect to the Go Daddy relay server.

Answer (score 2):

No 1. you can use native function of PHP called mail(). for more details http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

here you have to setup SMPT details in your php.ini file or u can overwrite itfrom your code.

No 2. Use PHPMailer Library.Very much easy to integrate. 
you can get it from http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Answer (score 1):

Have you included some php library which supports sendmail?

If you're trying to use the OS command sendmail, this won't work like that.

PHPs mail function isn't recommended so use something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Comment: Thank you very much for everybody i have got it working thanks al lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the php file in which defination of method sendMail is written and then include it . If by chance its in same directory then simply add this line on top

```
require_once 'sendmail.php' ;
```

Comment: kindly down-rate with some constructive response